# Clarification require on offline data authentication

Tags: emv, verifone

If card support SDA + DDA , At what condition POS will not perform SDA/DDA operation?? Is ODA performed by POS decided on basis of tag 82 only? or other tags/values check by the terminal to decide - ODA need to perform or not...

For me - DDA check card is genuine or not and no data altered inside it so it must be performed by any terminal.

Also I believe CA pubic key require to decrypt the certificate and here RID + Tag 8F used to get the correct key from key repository. Is it correct?

Comment: You have an exciting imagination and feelings, but better to look into EMV 4.3 Book 3 "Application Specification" where in pp 10.3 "Offline Data Authentication" the necessary conditions described. Yes, CA Public Keys required at the terminal for ODA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If card support SDA + DDA , At what condition POS will not perform SDA/DDA operation??
```

POS will not perform SDA/DDA only when POS is **not able** for perform offline Transaction

```
Is ODA performed by POS decided on basis of tag 82 only?
```

Yes, Tag 82 tells, card support offline data authentication or not. Performing ODA is depend on capability of card and terminal. If Tag 82, DDA bit is 1 and terminal support offline data authentication, terminal must perform DDA.

```
Also I believe CA pubic key require to decrypt the certificate and here RID + Tag 8F used to get the correct key from key repository. Is it correct?
```

Each terminal/POS have different CA public keys that is require to decrypt the certificate. At the time of transaction , POS read RID and Tag 8F ( index) from the card and fetch the corresponding key from key Repository. same key is used to decrypt the certificate.

Can check more about ODA [Here....](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwicy6aL_b_NAhUT12MKHfzSBdcQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftsys.com%2FAssets%2FTSYS%2Fdownloads%2Fbr_faq-on-offline-data-authentication.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH2NKTkjsXyqu4DRUAcR5L-Iw0djg&sig2=gas6hb99D_v_xVYAtYuA9A&bvm=bv.125596728,bs.2,d.dGo)

hope this information is up to the mark, Any correction/updation are welcome.